# Count days within overlapping date ranges in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, date

I have a large amount of date FROM and TO pairs, and I need to count all the days within them. But if two ranges are overlapping then the overlapping days should not be counted twice.

Here's the code that counts all days that I have:

```
Dim total_days_used = 0
For Each row As DataRow In MY_DATA.Tables(0).Rows
    Dim total_days As Double = 0

    Dim date_from = MY_FROM_DATE_FROM_DATA
    Dim date_to = MY_TO_DATE_FROM_DATA

    Dim span = date_to - date_from

    total_days = span.TotalDays '=4
    total_days_used += total_days
Next
```

I can't figure out an easy way to subtract the overlapping days though or even keep track of them. I guess that would be one way to go, the other would be to combine overlapping ranges until I end up with a set of ranges where there are no overlaps but that seems way too complicated as well. There should be a simple way to do this?

Comment: As you iterate you could put overlapping dates in a list or dictionary so you would know which ones were already counted

Comment: I would get a list of ranges without overlap first. Loop and merge and overlapping range in an other list. Then you can get the amount of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.
We first order the ranges to know if the last overlaps the current.
And then count the overlapping days and substract that from the total.
+1 days if you want the range to be inclusive otherwise remove that.

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim ranges = New List(Of Range)() From { _
        {New Range(New DateTime(2000, 1, 1), New DateTime(2000, 1, 30))}, _
        {New Range(New DateTime(2000, 1, 28), New DateTime(2000, 2, 3))} _
    }
    CountNonOverlappingsDays(ranges).Dump() '34 days
End Sub

Private Function CountNonOverlappingsDays(ranges As IEnumerable(Of Range)) As Integer    
    Dim isFirst = True
    Dim last As Range = Nothing
    Dim overlapping As Integer = 0
    Dim total As Integer = 0
    For Each current In ranges.OrderBy(Function(r) r.[To])
        total += CInt((current.[To] - current.From).TotalDays) + 1 '+1 if we want Inclusive count

        If isFirst Then
            isFirst = False
            last = current
            Continue For
        End If
        If (last.From <= current.[To]) AndAlso (last.[To] >= current.From) Then
            Dim start = current.From
            Dim [end] = last.[To]
            overlapping += CInt(([end] - start).TotalDays) + 1 '+1 if we want Inclusive count
        End If
        last = current
    Next
    Return total - overlapping
End Function

   Public Class Range
    Public Sub New([from] As DateTime, [to] As DateTime)
        [From] = [from]
        [To] = [to]
    End Sub
    Public Property [From]() As DateTime
        Get
            Return m_From
        End Get
        Set
            m_From = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_From As DateTime
    Public Property [To]() As DateTime
        Get
            Return m_To
        End Get
        Set
            m_To = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_To As DateTime
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you, managed to get it working almost without tweaking. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following (or similar `DateRange` class).

```
Class DateRange
    Implements IEnumerable(Of DateTime)
    Public Sub New(startDate As DateTime, endDate As DateTime)
        me.StartDate = startDate
        me.EndDate = endDate
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property StartDate() As DateTime
    Public ReadOnly Property EndDate() As DateTime

    Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of DateTime) Implements IEnumerable(of DateTime).GetEnumerator
        Return Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + EndDate.Subtract(StartDate).Days).[Select](Function(offset) StartDate.AddDays(offset)).GetEnumerator()
    End Function

    Private Function IEnumerable_GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Return GetEnumerator()
    End Function
End Class
```

The important part of this class is that it is enumerable. That is, it returns the sequence of dates between the start and end dates (inclusive), when used in a `for each` loop (among other things).

Then you can use code like this to get what you want:

```
Dim ranges = New List(Of DateRange)()
ranges.Add(New DateRange(#2017/1/1#,#2017/1/10#))
ranges.Add(New DateRange(#2017/1/8#,#2017/1/20#))

Dim merged = ranges.SelectMany(Function(r) r.AsEnumerable()).Distinct().OrderBy(Function(dt) dt)
Console.WriteLine($"{merged.Count()} days: ")
For Each [date] As DateTime In merged
    Console.WriteLine([date].ToShortDateString())
Next
Console.ReadLine()
```

This uses the LINQ `SelectMany` function to flatten the lists of dates (created by the `IEnuemrable` `DateRange`) from all the `DateRange` instances in the list to a single list of `DateTime`. It then gets the distinct (unique) values, and sorts the list.

The output shows output from a list containing 2 `DateRange` instances. The first is from Jan 1, 2017 to Jan 10, 2017, the second from Jan 8, 2017 to Jan 20, 2017.  These ranges overlap on the 8th, 9th, and 10th. As you can see, those overlapped dates are only included once.

The following output is produced:

> 20 days:
>   1/1/2017
>   1/2/2017
>   1/3/2017
>   1/4/2017
>   1/5/2017
>   1/6/2017
>   1/7/2017
>   1/8/2017
>   1/9/2017
>   1/10/2017
>   1/11/2017
>   1/12/2017
>   1/13/2017
>   1/14/2017
>   1/15/2017
>   1/16/2017
>   1/17/2017
>   1/18/2017
>   1/19/2017
>   1/20/2017

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim range As New List(Of DateTime)()

For Each row As DataRow In MY_DATA.Tables(0).Rows
    Dim date_from = MY_FROM_DATE_FROM_DATA
    Dim date_to = MY_TO_DATE_FROM_DATA
    range.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, (date_from-date_to).TotalDays).Select(d => date_from.AddDays(d))
Next
Dim total_days_used As Integer = range.Distinct().Count()
```

The magic is in two parts. The first part uses `Enumerable.Range()` to actually project all of the dates in each range, so we can add them to a list. The second part then just takes the distinct members of that list and counts them.